# Shopify: My Theme won't allow me to "Add Section" and native widgets

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-template

I have a theme for a client's Shopify site. Typically when I work in Shopify, when editing page/product templates there is an "Add Section" and "Add Block" as seen in the below picture. But for this theme there is none. Can I update the .liquid template to allow this functionality or am I stuck because of the theme:

**Client's Theme:**

[image]

**What I would like to see:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify introduced sections everywhere in online store 2.0. That option to add dynamic sections and blocks gets enabled when you have json templates. So you will have to migrate the templates to json format.  The reason why it's missing in this theme is that this theme has legacy .liquid templates.

More details:
https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/architecture/templates/json-templates